# Pygame sprite not moving while jumping

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I'm confused why my sprite is not moving while jumping. I've checked several times and changed my code over and over with no luck. My code is below and contains 3 pages, first contain the main loop, second contain the player class and third contain some game functions.

Main

```
import pygame
from player import Player
import game_functions as gf
import sys
import time

def run_game():
    # Intialise the game and start the screen
    pygame.init()   
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("AmarCreep")
    
    player = Player(screen)
    
    # Main loop
    while True:
        
        # Navy screen
        screen.fill((0,0,128))
        
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Check if user wants to quit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            gf.responses(screen, player, event)
            
        player.p_movements()
        
        
        # Make the player appear
        player.draw_player()
        
        
        # Make the newly made screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
    
run_game()
```

Player

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Player(Sprite):
    # Initialise the main player
    
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        
        # Specifying the position of the player at start 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = 590
        
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.y = 30
        self.y_ud = 5
        
        
    def p_movements(self):
        
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.x > 5:
            self.rect.x -= 1
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.x < 765:
            self.rect.x += 1    
        if self.moving_up:
            self.rect.y -= self.y
            self.y -= 2
            if self.y == -30:
                self.moving_up = False
                self.y = 30
                self.rect.bottom = 590
            pygame.time.delay(20)   
        
                
            
            
            
    def draw_player(self):
        ''' Draw the player on the screen'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255,255,255), self.rect)
```

Game functions

```
import pygame


def responses(screen, player, event):
    ''' Check for responses'''
    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player.moving_up = True
            
                
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player.moving_left = True
                
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player.moving_right = True
                
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        
                
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player.moving_left = False
                
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player.moving_right = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the player moves when you jump, but it is hardly noticeable in the case of " `self.moving_up` due to `pygame.time.delay(20)`.
Remove `delay` from your code, but increase the movement of the player:

```py
class Player(Sprite):

    def p_movements(self):
        
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.x > 5:
            self.rect.x -= 5                         # <---
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.x < 765:
            self.rect.x += 5                         # <--- 
        if self.moving_up:
            self.rect.y -= self.y
            self.y -= 2
            if self.y == -30:
                self.moving_up = False
                self.y = 30
                self.rect.bottom = 590
            # pygame.time.delay(20)                    <--- DELETE
```

But use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

```py
def run_game():
    # [...]
    
    # Main loop
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)

        # [...]
```

[image]